# Azure DevOps AAD tab shows a user that does not exists as disconnected

Tags: azure-devops

1 member(s) of the *XXX* organization can't sign in because they're not in the *YYY* Azure Active Directory. Delete any unwanted users in Organization settings, and then Resolve for remaining members.

This 1 user does not exists in the organization or somehow I cannot find it. The user was already deleted. How do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This user was not visible but it showed up when called through the Azure DevOps API:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

I deleted the user by calling the following API:

```
DELETE https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users/{userDescriptor}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Remember adding Authorization header:

```
Authorization:Basic <: and your PAT in Base64 string>
```

Comment: was this the solution? if so, mark this as the answer.

Comment: Yes, this was the solution, but i'll have to wait 2 days to accept it as answer. :(